# Can I connect two Ethernet ports on the same adapter on the same host to test to check port performance and perform stress test?

Tags: performance, ethernet, stress

I have one Ethernet card with two 10G ports. I cannot verify the port performance and do a stress test by card to card with different systems. I would like to verify the port performance and stress test by connecting port A and port B on the same adapter on the single card, assign each port an IP address, and use iPerf to test?

I heard that by this way, since it is under the same OS, there will be no actual traffic generated between two ports.

I've been suggested to create a VM on the same system to separate both ports, so that it can make actual traffic to verify the performance and stress test, is that correct?

If I cannot connect both ports to verify the performance, how about below topology?

port A -> switch -> port B, where the switch is configured to forward the packet to port B.

Does this way make actual traffic?

Comment: Typically a virtualization host has a management adapter and network. You probably should ensure this adapter is separate from the host management adapter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have a good way to test this right this moment, but I would try using namespaces to isolate the interfaces, and then test them as you would with two different systems.

```
ip netns add test1
ip netns add test2
ip link set eth0 netns test1
ip link set eth1 netns test2
```

Then you can grab a shell in both namespaces with `ip netns exec test1 bash` and `ip netns exec test2 bash`, and then run your test as you've described.

Deleting these namespaces with `ip netns del testX` will bring your interfaces back to their normal configuration, but for completeness you can also move them back manually.

To move the interfaces back to the default namespace you can use `ip link set ethX netns 1` in each of the namespace shells, or `ip -n testX link set ethY netns 1` in the default namespace. In these commands, `1` refers to the PID of a process in the namespace you want to use, in this case the `init` process, which serves as the default for the system.

Comment: About losing interfaces: the *physical* interfaces will be returned to the host initial network namespace. But if the system was already running in a namespace (eg: as a container),then the interfaces, because they return to the initial namespace rather than the current container namespace become "lost". Virtual interfaces (incl. veth of container) are deleted.Also, if there is still a resource using the "deleted" (ie: unmounted by ip netns) namespace, then the interfaces won't move. Can be easy  (/proc/PID/ns/net) or difficult (/proc/PID/fd/X) to recover depending on what kind of resource.

Comment: Of course moving interfaces back to where they came from as you wrote before attempting to delete the namespace is the best way.

Comment: @A.B Right you are, I know I did have this happen to me and assumed that was how it worked. Possibly I was looking at a veth and got myself confused, or one of the other situations you described. I did use a containerized wireguard tunnel configuration on my work laptop for a while, and I could easily myself pretty muddled up keeping track of everything. Edited the post

Comment: Interesting how everybody is happy with a linux solution when OP never mentioned their OS.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, I'm sorry that you have to deal with that other os</could_not_resist>

Comment: @GuntramBlohm I think it's a great solution even if OP isn't running a linux OS, considering how easy it is to get a live environment going and the nature of a one-off performance test, this is a solution anyone can deploy, and carries none of the overhead that a VM would. It's good feedback though, in truth it didn't even cross my mind that OP wouldn't want to use linux 

Comment: @akostadinov No reason to be sorry, I had my first contact with Unix back in 1985 and stopped dealing with non-Unix-like OSes in 2015. (Please, don't start a discussion how Unix-like Linux is!). It just amazes me how normalized "professional question? Assume Linux!" has become.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, for what it's worth, can I point out that there are (more like were) UNIX certified linux distributions? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476945/14907